# Does every compact simply-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ have an efficient $r$-covering path for all $r>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $A$ denote a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Definition 0.** Given a positive real number $r$, an *$r$-covering path of $A$* is a non-negative real number $T$ together with a differentiable function $c:[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying: for all $a \in A$, there exists $t \in [0,T]$ such that $\|a - c(t)\| \leq r.$

*Remark.* I'm not especially attached to the details of the above definition. For example, you may wish to replace "differentiable" with "rectifiable." Or, you may wish to include an assumption that $c'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [0,T],$ in order to remove the possibility of "kinks" from the path. So basically, use whatever definition makes the question easier to answer in the affirmative.

**Definition 1.** An $r$-covering path of $A$ is *efficient* iff there is no $r$-covering path of strictly shorter length.

I reckon the following question is pretty interesting, especially if the answer is "yes."

> **Question.** Is it true that for all $r>0$, every compact simply-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an efficient $r$-covering path?

The conditions "compact and simply-connected" were basically plucked out of thin air to in order to eliminate weird and silly counterexamples. Anyway, feel free to modify them as you see fit. The same goes for "differentiable": feel free to replace this with "smooth" or even "analytic" if it makes for a cleaner answer.

Comment: The length of a path $c\colon\left[0,T\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is $T$, I assume?

Comment: @par, not without further assumptions. The length of the path is $\int_0^T\|c'(t)\|dt,$ by definition. But we can assume wlog that the path has unit speed (i.e. $\|c'(t)\|$) in which case yes, its length is just $T$.

Comment: So, for example, if $A$ was a disk of radius $2$, would the unit circle $c:t\mapsto e^{it}$ be a $1$-covering path?

Comment: @columbus8myhw, that's right.

Comment: And for higher radii of the disk, I guess some sort of spiral would probably do it.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, that was my feeling too. Hard to prove anything though...

Comment: No, space filling curves are not compact. But given that, isn't the problem trivial? Any compact set belongs to some closed ball/hypercube and since it is clearly possible to cover a closed ball/hypercube, it is possible to cover any compact set.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, the title question is a little deceptive. But the question as stated in the body of the question is more precise.

Comment: You could restrict yourself to $1$-coverings, right? Because an $r$-covering of a set $A$ is basically a $1$-covering of a resized version of $A$, except dilated.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, that's right.

Comment: I'm curious what an efficient covering for a ball (sphere with its interior) would be.

Comment: @goblin: Why is it clear that an efficient $r$-covering path $c$ has $c'(t) \neq 0$? Perhaps the most efficient curve for some set $A$ has kinks?

Comment: @MikeMiller, hmm good point. This is what happens when a non-analyst asks questions about analysis. So if I understand correctly, assume $c'(t) \neq 0$ is "equivalent" to assuming 'no kinks' in this particular situation. Is that right?

Comment: @goblin: It's always true that if $c'(t) \neq 0$ then there are no "kinks", because this is precisely the condition that it be an immersion - that is, there is a smooth chart such that $c$ (restricted to $(t-\varepsilon, t+\varepsilon)$ just traces out the $x$-axis. But, say, I can give you a smooth curve $c$ that traces out the graph of $|x|$; at this kink-point we necessarily have $c'(t) = 0$.

Comment: @MikeMiller, wait, wouldn't the assumption that $c'$ has a kink somewhere violate the assumption that $c$ is differentiable?

Comment: The claim is that if $c$ has a kink at $t$, then $c'(t) = 0$.

Comment: "Differentiable" or any stronger assumption is going to complicate things, for sure.  Maybe you would rather specify "Lipschitz" or "rectifiable"?  Anyway, my instinct would be to take a sequence of $r$-covering paths whose lengths approach the infimum, and try to use Arzela-Ascoli to produce a subsequential limit that should be a minimizer.

Comment: @NateEldredge, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Minimizing in continuous paths creates both "kinks" and "doubling." This can be seen in "petal shaped" sets. For example, let $R$ be a rectangle with side lengths $l >> w$. Let $p\in R$ be a point very close to a side of length $w$. Let $K$ be the union of the rotations of $R$ about $p$ by multiples of $2\pi/3$. So, $K$ is a three petal like shape.

Intuitively, any continuous path must double back inside at least one petal of $K$. For $r=w/2$, it is reasonable that the minimizer double backs on top of itself after "kinking" near the tip of the petal.

Comment: What if $A$ is itself an image of an unrectifible curve? In that case is there even an $r$-covering path?

Comment: @JohnMa The path doesn't have to lie in $A$. For any compact set there is an $r$-covering path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Rectifiable case

The [comment by Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1420109#comment2893545_1420109) solves this one. Indeed, let $L$ be the infimal length of $r$-covering paths, and pick a sequence of such paths $\gamma_n$ of length at most $ L+1/n$. Each of them can be represented by an $(L+1/n)$-Lipschitz map from $[0,1]$. These maps are also uniformly bounded, since the paths visit the $r$-neighborhood of the same bounded set. By the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, there is a uniformly convergent subsequence $\gamma_{n_k}$. Its limit $\gamma$ has length at most $   L$, since length is lower semicontinuous under uniform convergence. It also visits the $r$-neighborhood of every point of $A$. Hence, the length of $\gamma$ is $L$, and it is an efficient $r$-covering path.

Note that we don't need any assumptions on $A$ other than boundedness.

#### Smooth case

Within differentiable curve, the infimal length need not be attained. For example, let $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ be the broken line from 
$A(0,3)$ to $B(0,0)$ to $C(3,0)$, and let $r=\sqrt{2}$. There is a non-differentiable $r$-covering path of length $2(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2})$, shown below: it is obtained
from the broken line $AEC$ where $E=(1,1)$, by cutting off the pieces of length $r$ near $A$ and $C$.

[image: covering]

To prove minimality, let $\gamma$ be another shorter $r$-covering path. It must contain a point within distance $\sqrt{2}$ of $(0,0)$, call this point $Z$. As a calculus exercise, one can verify that $|AZ|+|CZ|\ge 2\sqrt{5}$, attained only if $Z=(1,1)$. (Or, instead of using calculus, recall that the locus of points of constant distance-sum from $A$ and $C$ is an ellipse  with $A$ and $C$ as foci.) Since $\gamma $ must also visit an $r$-neighborhood of $A$ and $r$-neighborhood of $C$, it follows that its length is at least $2(\sqrt{5}-r)$, as realized by $DEF$ on the sketch. (The angle $\angle DEF$ is greater than $120$ degrees, which implies that the union of $DE$ and $EF$ is the shortest continuum containing $D,E,F$, the Fermat point of this triangle.)